# RestKit -- how can I get child object data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

All,

This must be an answer that only I lack, since I can't find an answer anywhere.
I am learning RestKit on ios, and have finally managed to get it to properly consume JSON, complete with a relationship (woohoo!).

However, I cannot figure out how I am to access the fields/data of the child class from the parent class.

Example JSON:
   {
     events {
      name : "Fitness Walk",
      desc : "walking in circles"
      location {
          placename : "your backyard",
          longitude : -40.1234,
          latitude  : 38.5678,
          address : "1600 Penn"
      }
   }

So I have an event class and a location class.  The event class has a pointer to the location as a member variable (EventLocation * toLocation) to contain the relationship:

```
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];

RKEntityMapping * locationMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"EventLocation" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
NSDictionary * locationInfo = @{ @"placename" : @"eventPlaceName", @"longitude" : @"longitude", @"latitude" : @"latitude", @"address" : @"eventAddress" };
[locationMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:locationInfo];

RKEntityMapping * eventMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"NYCEvent" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
NSDictionary * eventInfo = @{ @"_id" : @"event_id", @"name" : @"event_name",@"desc" : @"event_description" };
[eventMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:eventInfo];

[eventMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"location" toKeyPath:@"toLocation" withMapping:locationMapping]];

RKResponseDescriptor * responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:eventMapping pathPattern:@"/api/search" keyPath:@"events" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

And as in the tutorials, I would like to put the eventPlaceName text as a subtitle in the UITableViewCell.

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"event_name"] description];


    NSString * lbl = < somehow get the event place name>;


    cell.detailTextLabel.text = lbl;
}
```

But I don't know how.  Help me please?

Thanks!
:bp:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Key-Value Coding:

```
NSManagedObject *object = ... // your Event object
NSString *placeName = [object valueForKeyPath:@"toLocation.eventPlaceName"];
```

It gets easier if you create managed object subclasses (Xcode->Editor->Create NSManagedObject Subclass ...). Then you can use the properties of the objects:

```
Event *event = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = event.event_name;
NSString *lbl = event.toLocation.eventPlaceName;
```

Comment: Thanks!  although it didn't work quite as advertised.  What I ended up doing was:   `Location * location = [event valueForKey:@"toLocation]; NSString * lbl = location.eventPlaceName;`

Comment: @BillyPilgrim: `[event valueForKey:@"toLocation]` and `event.toLocation` *should* be equivalent. Did you get a compiler error with my proposed code?

Comment: no compiler error -- runtime.  Went off into the weeds, with a core data error.  "A serious error has occurred' or something like that.

Comment: CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  -[NYCEvent where]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x766ef00 with userInfo (null)